# Prevent any object from being highlighted upon touch event

Tags: javascript, html, windows-phone-8, kineticjs

I am creating an application for mobile ( html5,kinetic.js).
I use nokia lumia 920 for testing.
The problem is when i push/click/touch anything on the application created with (kinetic-v5.0.1.min.js ) the screen flickers (it is something like an "transparent grey layer pops up")

There is an way to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

In css you can do something like:

```
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: <color>;
```

Comment: i have tried this already on the device nokia lumia 920 doesn't work